# How to check if lines in homogenous coordinates are distinct?

Tags: geometry

In $\mathbb{P}^3$ the 4 lines in homogeneous coordinates are given:
$$g = [1:-1:1], h = [1:1:0], k = [3:-3:-1], l = [1:0:0]$$

Show that g, h, k, l are all pairwise distinct and that each three of them build the sides of a triangle.

I don't quite understand how we can check if two lines are distinct in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by lines? in my opinion those are just 4 points in the projective space (if you wish, lines through the origin). However, if you interpret them as actual lines in $\mathbb{k}^n$ we get that  all go through the origin, and hence the second part of the question makes no sense. Are you sure you did not miss some variable in the definition? especially since lines in homogenous coordinates sounds like lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for not specifying. I edited the question. The lines are in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: they are however still points in $\mathbb{P}^3$ not lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: You can have points and lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$. If you calculate the connection line between two points you get a line in this form. And in this case, we have lines.

Comment: so you mean that you want to consider the 6 lines defined by those points? then please make that clear! also, is it now 4 or 6, since 4 points define 6 lines. I am sorry for pestering, but this question is far from clearly stated.

Comment: No, these are already the 4 lines.

Comment: no, these are 4 points in $\mathbb{P}3$, which by counting define $6$ lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and since you implied in your previous comment that you are intrested in those lines defined by two of those points, it sounds to me like it should say $6$ lines defined by the $4$ points in $\mathbb{P}^3$. As I said, please be clear!
also, it might be wise to say which field you are working over, since over $\mathbb{F}_2$ a lot might collapse.

Comment: I think you do not quite understand what I mean. A line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ can be represented as - $u_1x_1 + u_2x_2 + u_3x_3 = 0$. $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are the homogenious coordinates of the line. And these are exaclty the ones I have defined in my question.

Comment: ah, ok now I see! thanks a lot! still, I would restrict to a field with $char(k)\neq 2$
regarding the line question, I would suggest you look at the defining equations in $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ and consider the corresponding homogenous ideals.

Comment: Isn’t all this going on in the projective plane $\mathbb P^2$, not the projective _space_ $\mathbb P^3$? Lines in the latter can’t be represented by a single three-element vector, but they can in the former.

Comment: Anyway, how would you determine whether or not a pair of homogeneous coordinate triples represent distinct points? Apply point-line duality to that, or, as @Enkidu suggested, think about the conditions for the equations $\mathbf l^T\mathbf x = 0$ and $\mathbf m^T\mathbf x$ to represent the same line.